# NetStream.seek() for mp4 to exact position not keyframe

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mp4

It seems `seek()` on mp4 file seeks to the closest keyframe (seekpoint). Is it possible to seek to exact position in between of keyframes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does in fact seek to the nearest key frame. If you want to be able to seek to more specific parts of the stream you'll need to add more key frames. Of course more key frames usually results in larger file size. Good luck!

Comment: I think it's the other way round. More keyframes mean less processor time, because there's more data and less stuff to interpolate (though it trades off space, i.e. it takes more memory/bandwidth).